# Player falling through the floor Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies, collider

I have a rigidbody and a collider on the floor and the player, both labeled not triggers, and player still falls through the floor. The physics settings allow collisions between everything, but the player still falls through the floor. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: does the player have a rigidbody? attach screenshots of all the components in your situation

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/VJHKcsm)

Answer (score 2):

- You should either use CharacterController or Rigidbody, not both at the same time (a kinematic Rigidbody is fine, though). See tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e94KggaEAr4
- Make sure to reset velocity y value in your Movement script when the character controller is grounded. Otherwise, speed will continuously increase and the character controller may pass through the ground when it reaches an immense speed.

Comment: The whole - don't mix CharacterControllers and Rigidbodys was helpful, especially for multiplayer setups: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/183406/112686

Answer (score 0):

As far as is can see your grass game object is the floor. It might be possible that your player is standing within the box collider of the grass and therefore is falling through it.

Try to place your player above the highest point of the grass and see whether he is falling through or standing on top now.
If he is standing on top the solution to  your problem could be placing a plane underneath the grass and simply attach a box collider to it so it can function as a floor. You won't see the plane and you can walk through your grass without falling through the floor anymore.